# Tips and steps for setting up ruby on rails continuous integration server with github integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration

I'm still new with ruby on rails and am tasked with setting up a continuous integration server/service that uses the code hosted on github and alerts when the tests fails. Amazon EC2 was recommended as a service to use as platform for the service. 
I did some research and tried to set up the system using a step by step tutorial but I'm not used to work with Amazon EC2, so I kinda failed doing that.

Can you help me with some advices or first steps to take?

Thanks

Comment: So your requirements are: use the code hosted on Github or the source code of Github? What is the programming language(s) you are interested in? Do you know the CI feature matrix of ThoughtWorks (http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CI server you can use CruiseControl developed by [ThoughWorks](http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/documentation)

. Its open source as well . You can get it from [github](https://github.com/thoughtworks/cruisecontrol.rb) as well.

And pretty much simple to set up only takes 10 min to setup and as its written in ruby its pretty much simple to hack and customize to as per your need .
Reply me if you find anything problem in setup CI
Thanks